# service is running in console application but not in web asp.net

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I am consuming one service when i consume service in Console Application it works fine but  same is not working in Web application .

Error: There was no endpoint listening at 'web service name here' that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.

I tried to browse Service End points in Browser and i am able to get response.I am using visual studio 2012

Please help me.

Thanks,
Kapil

Comment: Are you using ChannelFactory or did you add a reference to the service is VS ?

Comment: i created proxy class using svcutil.exe

Comment: can you give us the service and endpoint configuration portion from your config file (both client side and server side)

Answer (score 0):

By adding below section in web config i am able to solve my problem.

```
     <system.net>
      <defaultProxy>
        <proxy usesystemdefault="False"/>
      </defaultProxy>
     </system.net>
```